# Capitalize the word "markdown" in formatting tips and editing help

Tags: bug, markdown, editing-help, capitalization

When editing a post (old or new editor likewise), there is a button to get formatting tips. The page about tables has the word "markdown" written in lower case:

[image]

The same issue also appears in the [editing help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables):

[image]

Comment: I'd say this is more of a [bug], since Markdown is *supposed* to be capitalized, but it's not  (in the areas you point out).

Comment: Yeah, I have no problems if this would be tagged as a bug.

Comment: While we’re at it, [the official spec](https://github.github.com/gfm/) says “GitHub Flavored Markdown” (no hyphen, “flavored” is also capitalized with everything else). IMO, if they change it, SE should use that capitalization and remove the hyphen. Interestingly, that spec spells SO as “StackOverflow” (no space), so maybe it is wrong…? The hyphen seems grammatically right, but IMO it should be spelled like in the spec